# Sharepoint Online and custom BDC models

Tags: bcs, sharepoint-online, bdc-model, rest

Hello I hope somebody can help.

I need to access an external timesheet from Sharepoint Online. 
The Timesheet site uses a REST api to provide the data, not a WCF or traditional ASPX webservice. So you call a URL and get XML back.

I've found the Business Data Connectivity Services which would be great from Sharepoint Designer if it was one of the standard supported types.

But I've seen that you can write custom *.bdcm to provide a map to the data.

This is made difficult because as far as I can see you can't upload a DLL to the BDCS as a go between it has to all be done in the *.bdcm which is hand written XML.

There must be a better way to do this. If it was normal sharepoint then it would be done in code nice and easy, but as far as I know sharepoint online doesn't allow you to upload the DLL along with the bdcm.

Does anyone have any advice on this subject? How do you go about accessing external content on Sharepoint Online which requires a custom model?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately so far BCS for SharePoint online can only support Windows Azure data sources. I would try client-side integration like here: http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/SharePoint-Online-and-External-Data-using-JSONP.aspx